# Is it possible to add more than one environment variable to PyDev at once?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Running PyDev with Eclipse, I can see in the Run Configurations window how to add environment variables. You just click Add and provide the name and value.

I need to add over 20 of them to at least two configurations. Adding them one at a time is...suboptimal. There does not appear to be a function to add more than one at once.

Is there a way to add multiple environment variables at once? I already have them listed as `=`-separated pairs in a `.txt` file, if that would help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to save the launch config as a file:

Run > run configurations > select launch > select common tab > save as > shared file: say where you want to save it.

Then, you can add a sample variable just to know how to enter it, open the .launch file and edit it as text to add the variables you want.

But still, just to note, this may not be what you're after... if you always have the same variables, you can simply create a .bat to configure those variables in a shell and launch eclipse from that shell to inherit those variables.

Or if you have already configured them in the shell, you could just select them in the environment tab (instead of putting 'new' each time, you can click 'select' and add multiple variables at once with the values already pre-configured).

Or if those variables are interpreter-dependent, you can configure them in the interpreter configuration (window > preferences > pydev > intererpreter - python > environment).